# Определить местоположение фразы в строке

Tags: javascript

```
var match = "Спартак Москва - Динамо Киев";
```

Как в данной строке определить "Динамо Киев" играет дома или на выезде, то есть находится ли передней "- " или нет, учитывая, что название оппонента нам не известно. Чтоб потом записать в виде.

```
var match = {teams: "Спартак Москва - Динамо Киев", home: false};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Этого хотите?

```
"Спартак Москва - Динамо Киев".indexOf('Динамо Киев') == 0;
```

Comment: так еще проще, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
function home(match)
{
      var n = match.indexOf("Динамо Киев");
      if(n==0) return true;
      else return false;
}
```